# Not getting the desired output through Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Below is my code.I am trying to implement Linked List.Below are my 3 classes.Node.java LinkedList.java and Main class.My code gets hanged.I tried to debug but not finding the exact issue.As far as I can see there is some issue in the add method itself.Please help.

```
package com.vikash.LinkedList;

public class Node {

    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    public  Node(Object data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}


package com.vikash.LinkedList;

public class LinkedList {

    public Node head;

    public void add(Object data)
    {
        Node temp=new Node(data);

        if(head==null)
        {
            head=temp;

        }

        Node current=head;

        while(current.getNext()!=null)
        {
            current=current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
    }

    public void add(Object data,int index)
    {

    }

    public int get(int index)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean remove(int index)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Node current=head;
        System.out.println(current.getData());
        while(current!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(current.getData());
            System.out.print("->");
            current=current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("X");
    }
}

package com.vikash.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList linkedList=new LinkedList();
        linkedList.add(1);
        linkedList.add(2);
        linkedList.add(3);
        linkedList.add(4);

        linkedList.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: General comment/warning: The Java collections class has something already called `LinkedList`, so you should probably not give your class the same name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for pointing it out.Will keep it in mind.Can you please find the issue.

Comment: Have a look at my answer.  I gave you a full implementation for your `add()` method.

Answer (score 4):

When you add the first node, you must not execute the rest of the logic :

```
    if(head==null)
    {
        head=temp;
        return; // add this
    }
```

Currently, when adding the first node, you are adding the same `Node` twice, linking it to itself, thus creating an infinite list :

```
1 -> 1 -> 1 -> ...
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Such as?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of your `com.vikash.LinkedList.add()` method.  I also noticed that several of your other methods are either not implemented or may have problems.  But since your immediate failures seem to be coming from the `add()` method, hopefully this will set you on the right track.

```
public void add(Object data) {
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node curr = head;

    if (curr == null) {
        // if the list be empty, assign the head
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        // otherwise walk down the list until hitting the end
        while (curr.getNext() != null) {
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

        // and the insert the new node
        curr.setNext(temp);
    }

    return;
}
```